# Changes in eventSources model do not reflect in fullCalendar

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, restangular

Im using angularjs, restangular & angular-ui/ui-calendar.
I want to load events from rest API when view is changed (next/prev month, etc.) 
I'm trying to do that from `viewRender` callback.
Inside callback, data is retrieved from API and applied to `eventSources` model. However changes in model do not get applied in calendar.

Someone please point out what is wrong or if I'm missing anything.

I've tried `fullCalendar('render')`, `rerenderEvents`, `refetchEvents` etc. The calendar keeps showing initial events set in controller.

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="visitCal"></div>


myControllers.controller('CalenderCtrl',['$scope','uiCalendarConfig','Restangular',function($scope,uiCalendarConfig,Restangular){

    var fetchEvents=function(view,element){
        var cal=uiCalendarConfig.calendars.visitCal;

        var visits=Restangular.all('visits');
        visits.getList({start:view.start.format(),end:view.end.format()}).
            then(function(visits) {
                $scope.eventSources.events=[];
                for(var i= 0;i < visits.length;i++){
                    $scope.eventSources.events.push(visits[i]);
                }
                cal.fullCalendar('render');
            }
        );
    }; // end fetchEvents function
    $scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar:{
            viewRender:fetchEvents,
            height: 450,
            editable: true,
            header:{
                left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'today prev,next'
            }
        }
    };
    //initial test events
    $scope.eventSources={events:[
        {title:'ev1',
            start:'2015-01-30',
            className:'testClass'},.......
    ]};

}]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone is stuck here.

approach shared by @slicedtoad is the right one however in angularjs, using callback of events function gives error in calendar.js.

Here's what I'm doing now.

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="visitCal"></div>

var fetchEvents=function(start, end, timezone, callback){
        var cal=uiCalendarConfig.calendars.visitCal;
        var visits=Restangular.all('visits');
                    visits.getList({start:start.format(),end:end.format()}).then(function(visits) {
            $scope.events.length=0;
            for(var i= 0;i < visits.length;i++){
                var event={
                    start: visits[i].start,
                    title:visits[i].title,
                };
                $scope.events.push(event);
            }
            //callback(new_events_array);->this gives error though it works
        });
    };

$scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar:{
            eventClick:eventInfo,
            events:fetchEvents,
            height: 450,
            editable: true,
            header:{....}
        }
    };
$scope.events=[];
$scope.eventSources=[$scope.events];
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't fetch events in viewRender.

Instead use `eventSources` as the event source. Two ways: [give it a callback](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) or [give it a JSON feed](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/).

**Callback method**

```
calendar: {
    height: 450,
    editable: true,
    header: {
        left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today prev,next'
    },
    events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) { // Fetch your events here
        // This could be an ajax call or you could get the events locally
        callback([{ 
            title: 'test1',
            start: moment()
        }, {
            title: 'test2',
            start: moment().add(2, 'hours')
        }]);
    }
}
```

**JSON feed method**

```
events: '/myfeed.php'
```

Where that script takes a date range returns a JSON array of events. For a more advanced version with data options see the [docs (scroll down to jQuery $.ajax options)](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/).

And if the data needs modified before being added, use [`eventDataTransform`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/)