# Events not displayed in jQuery FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm using jQuery FullCalendar converted to AngularJS, I'm getting events with HTTP Request and I want to show them in the calendar, I save those events in the plugin events object, but they are not displayed in the calendar.

[image: To the left are the events that I want to display in the calendar.]

This is the object that I'm using to save events that I get with HTTP Request, the array $scope.appointment_list contains the events that I'm displaying in the left list, the dates are in the default format established by the plugin, however I have not been able to display them in the calendar.

```
for(var i in $scope.appointments_list) {
    $scope.events.push({
        title: $scope.appointments_list[i].status,
        start: new Date($scope.appointments_list[i].date_start),
        end: new Date($scope.appointments_list[i].date_end),
        className: ['openSesame'],
        allDay: false,
        color: 'green',
        textColor: 'white',
        forceEventDuration: true
    });
}
```

What could be happening in the calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same bug and I don't why it happens. But in my case to fix this error was create an url in the **route provider**. Something like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/calendar/:somethingAjaxInfo', {
    templateUrl: 'calendar.html',
    controller: 'CalendarCtrl' });
```

And inside of *calendar.html* put the code of the full calendar. Also in the controller call the **http request** when the you send with the **route provider**.

I think the problem is because the controller try to call the **http request** when the info is empty, but if do an url in the **route provider** the calendar is render when this have all the info.

I wish this can help you

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked fine for me when I changed my calendar layout to a new HTML file with $routeProvider.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `$scope.events` object is passed to `eventSources` model for your calendar.
e.g.

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div>
```

In controller

```
$scope.events=[];
$scope.eventSources=[$scope.events];
```

Let me know if this doesn't solve your issue.

Also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28239074/4510680

Comment: Sorry man, that didn´t work for me, I already had eventSources array in that way.